# Dynamically adding a prefix to a named route in vue 2 / nuxt 2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs2

Pretty simple question, I am pushing a named route like so:

```
this.$nuxt.$router.push({ name: "my-named-route-id-foo", params: { id: this.$route.params.id } });
```

But I want to conditionally add a prefix to this so instead of the resulting URL always going to:

```
/my-named-route/32/foo
```

It might go to:

```
/prefix/my-named-route/32/foo
```

How do I insert the 'prefix' without resorting to a path route? (because I need to pass params on some of them and I don't want to use a query i.e. `?param=blahblah`)

I'm assuming it's probably using a custom middleware function, but I'm just not what to use to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Move your page "my-named-route" into a created folder named "prefix" in your Pages folder.

You can find more information in this page [Nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes)

edit:

> To create a dynamic route you need to add an underscore (_) before the
> .vue file name or before the name of the directory. You can name the
> file or directory anything you want but you must prefix it with an
> underscore.

File tree

```
pages/
--| prefix/
----| my-named-route/
------| _id.vue
------| index.vue
----| my-named-route.vue
```

**OR**
You can also do the conditional statement in the script where you call the router.push()

```
if(condition) {
    this.$nuxt.$router.push({ name: "my-named-route-id-foo", params: { id: this.$route.params.id } });
}
else {
    this.$nuxt.$router.push({ name: "prefix/my-named-route-id-foo", params: { id: this.$route.params.id } });
}
```

Comment: But that would not be dynamic... otherwise that's what I would have done.

Comment: See edited. If it doesn't answer your question, you can paste more about your code and code structure so we understand more what you want to do